# Ranking submissions based on multiple judges

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, standardization

I have a situation in which we have 20 proposals and five judges.

Each proposal is reviewed by **three of the five judges**, assigned to the proposal at random.

Each judge scores the proposal out of 100 points based on set criteria. However, the judges differ in how they score proposals (e.g., one judge gives lots of scores in the 90s, the other judge gives lots of scores in the 70s).

What is the best way to determine the ranking of proposals and the significance of that ranking? We would like to know which proposal "won"

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is turn each score into a [standard score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score), where you normalize each score based on the mean and standard deviation of each judge. So, for example, if Judge1's scores have mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, and Judge1 gives a score of $x$ to a given proposal, then the standard score for that individual is

$$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

Once all of your individual scores are converted to standard scores, you can rank them by average score to determine the winner. I am not sure what you mean by "significance of the ranking".

Comment: With regards to significance of the ranking: We normally get all of the judges in a room to determine the winner based on the top three or so submissions. I would like to be able to say that the first place proposal has a significantly higher score than the second place proposal. As such, there's no reason to have a further discussion. Maybe this should just be a t-test. However, with only three scores per proposal it will be very rare that we are confident enough in the results to skip the discussion step.